# Is there a "gradual style" available in QGIS to do something like this?

Tags: qgis, modelling

I need to print my map with something like this. I tested several styles in QGIS to represent this idea, but the closest I got was using the shapeburst fill.

The idea is:

1. The colors represent coverage levels. You can imagine the points as being antennas. The farther you are from it, the less coverage you have.
2. From the point up to 2km, there is 100% coverage
3. From 2km to 3km, coverage gradually decreases according to a distance function
4. The antennas can 'cooperate' with each other. When covered by 2 or more antennas, their probabilities add up.

If not possible in QGIS, would you recommend other tool where I can build it in the 2D plan?

Obs: I tried to reach out to the author, but I got no answer so far.

[image]

Source: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221721002058#fig0002

Comment: Why don't you start with reading the article and trying to create the coverage ratio layer?  What have you tried so far?  Are these data just a Euclidean distance surface or based on antenna visibility?

Comment: First of all, are you working with raster or vector data?

Comment: Point #4 is a matter of processing. If you have the antennas as seperate features or layers, you first need to create one coverage layer that a style can be applied to.
An oversimplified solution might be to create a heatmap based on the antenna points, but that would probably be unprecise

Comment: @GBG I've read the article and I have the data ready. These are Euclidean distances.

Comment: @MDollinger vector data

Comment: The values go from 0 to 1 so if it is a Euclidian distance surface it has been reclassified.  You can symbolize the output raster with a red to blue color gradient.  QGIS lets you alter (move) the gradiant stops so that you can simulate the graphic. The white dashed circles look to be a buffer around the points.  Unsure about the size of the red circle with crosses - that is the antenna data symbolized base on the value of some data in the attribute table.  Search the internet for instructions on those tasks (Euclidean distance and vector buffer), try them, and report back.

Comment: I was able to do the gradient color using the shapeburst and then adjusting the distance in the symbology window. But the problem is the cooperation (item 4) , this mixing effect when the buffers overlap, can't replicated it. I looked everywhere.

Comment: Using heatmap layer rendering would be an option?